# Parquet encryption and envelope technique with azure managed hsm

Tags: azure, apache-spark, encryption, parquet, hardware-security-module

I would like to use Columnar Encryption or parquet encryption with the envelope technique. I have read this [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#columnar-encryption).

An example of this technique for an open-source KMS is explained [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#kms-client)

My question is now is it possible to use Azure managed HSM instead of an open-source KMS? Do you know an example which uses MEK (master encryption keys), that is on Azure managed HSM to wrap/unwrap the DEKs (Data Encryption Keys) for parquet encryption?